# edit model with hasMany relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a problem when editing a model with relationships. I have a model 'Place' has multiple 'Contacts'.

When a user clicks on edit a site appears a form with fields place and fields of each contact (with the possibility of removing each contact), and a button that lets you add new contacts.

The problem is to submit the form: if it contains errors it is necessary to unhide the edit form. this phase will be necessary to show contacts with old values ​​updated in the first edition and new contacts, also included in the first edition.

My code: http://paste.laravel.com/zZe

in line 71 i'm showing the contacts fields of the place. in 82 I have a button to add the contacts (line 124). basicily, my problem is showing contacts old input (if exists)

### edit:

basically a place can have multiple contacts. when editing a location the user can edit or delete the contacts already established and create new ones. the problem here is if there is a validation failure is how I show contacts

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Do you need help updating the database when relationships, or help with displaying proper data on error? It will help us out a lot if you flesh out your question with more detail :D

Comment: my problem is how to display data when submit a form with errors, because users can be edited and/or added new contacts.